# Cómo aumentar el número de un objeto dentro de una matriz con un orden de identificación usando addEventListener

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

Tengo 6 productos en una matriz. Cuando quiero aumentar la cantidad del artículo, solo interpreta el primer producto de la matriz, aun así presiono los otros botones de los otros productos, y solo aumenta el primer artículo, solo me cambia en el primer producto.

Hice una búsqueda de identificadores para poder aumentar la cantidad del artículo.

Me gustaría poder solucionar el problema para aumentar los otros productos de la matriz.

```
const productos = [
    {
        id: 1,
        nombre: "Botella de Miel<br>950g",
        precio: 5000,
        cantidad: 1,
        img: "img/bp.png",
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        nombre: "Botella de Miel<br>500g",
        precio: 3000,
        cantidad: 1,
        img: "img/Botella_Med.png",
    },
    
    {
        id: 6,
        nombre: "Frasco de Miel con Panal<br>140g",
        precio: 2000,
        cantidad: 1,
        img: "img/fPq.png",
    }];

const doc = document.getElementById("pMain");

productos.forEach((p) => {
    let cta = document.createElement("div");
    cta.className = "card";
    cta.innerHTML = `
    <img src="${p.img}">
    <h3>${p.nombre}</h3>
    <p>₡ ${p.precio}</p>
    <div class="contCa">

    <button id="dis${p.id}" class="dismi"> - </button>
    <span class="num">${p.cantidad}</span>
    <button id="au${p.id}" class="aumentar"> + </button>

    </div>
    <button class="btnComprar">Añadir al carrito</button>`;
    doc.append(cta)

    /* Acciones de la cantidad de productos */
    const auMas = document.getElementById(`au${p.id}`);
    const tProd = document.querySelector(".num");

    auMas.addEventListener("click", () => {

        tProd.innerText = aumentarProducto(p.id);
    })

});

const aumentarProducto = (pId) => {
    const iProd = productos.find((i) => i.id === pId);

    return iProd.cantidad++; 
}
```

[image: Ejemplo de los botones]

Comment: Creo que te faltó colocar el código en donde se presiona el botón, además del html

Comment: los botones estan ahi con el innerHtml introduje html en javaScript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu problema es en esta sentencia:

```
const tProd = document.querySelector(".num");
```

La cual retornar el primer elemento que tiene la clase `num`, tu deberías ocupar la misma técnica que usaste con los botones, que es colocar una id que consta de un prefijo + el id del producto, algo así:

```
<span id="num${p.id}">${p.cantidad}</span>
const tProd =  document.getElementById(`num${p.id}`);
```

Además, tienes otro problema que es con la suma. Si te fijas debes presionar 2 veces el botón para sumar por primera vez, esto pasa porque el `++` lo pones al final, donde la suma se realiza a posterior, debes colocarla en el principio, es decir debes cambiar esto:

```
return iProd.cantidad++;
```

Por esto

```
return ++iProd.cantidad;
```

Ahora bien, en el ejemplo que te presento, yo cambie esto y ahora la función recibe un argumento que es la cantidad a sumar, de esta manera puedes usar la misma función para sumar un elemento, o restar un elemento.

```js
const productos = [
    {
        id: 1,
        nombre: "Botella de Miel<br>950g",
        precio: 5000,
        cantidad: 1,
        img: "img/bp.png",
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        nombre: "Botella de Miel<br>500g",
        precio: 3000,
        cantidad: 1,
        img: "img/Botella_Med.png",
    },
    
    {
        id: 6,
        nombre: "Frasco de Miel con Panal<br>140g",
        precio: 2000,
        cantidad: 1,
        img: "img/fPq.png",
    }];

const doc = document.getElementById("pMain");

productos.forEach((p) => {
    let cta = document.createElement("div");
    cta.className = "card";
    cta.innerHTML = `
    <img src="${p.img}">
    <h3>${p.nombre}</h3>
    <p>₡ ${p.precio}</p>
    <div class="contCa">

    <button id="dis${p.id}" class="dismi"> - </button>
    <span id="num${p.id}">${p.cantidad}</span>
    <button id="au${p.id}" class="aumentar"> + </button>

    </div>
    <button class="btnComprar">Añadir al carrito</button>`;
    doc.append(cta)

    /* Acciones de la cantidad de productos */
    const auMas = document.getElementById(`au${p.id}`);
    const aumenos = document.getElementById(`dis${p.id}`);
    const tProd =  document.getElementById(`num${p.id}`);

    auMas.addEventListener("click", () => {
        tProd.innerText = aumentarProducto(p.id,1);
    });
    aumenos.addEventListener("click", () => {
        tProd.innerText = aumentarProducto(p.id,-1);
    })

});

const aumentarProducto = (pId,cant) => {
    const iProd = productos.find((i) => i.id === pId);
    iProd.cantidad+=cant;
    return iProd.cantidad; 
}
```

```html
<div id="pMain"></div>
```